# General to specific: t-stat, Akaike, Schwarz, and Adjusted R-squared

Tags: regression, model-selection, least-squares

Specifying a linear model from general to specific i find that removing regressors corresponding to insignificant coefficients actually makes the adjusted r-squared, the Akaike and the Schwarz stats worse. Why does this happen? Should I ignore these parameters and keep on selecting regressors only looking at the t-stats?

Comment: For what reason do you want to select regressors in the first place?

Comment: I have a time-series linear model that tries to explain investment in residential real estate in the US. Very rudimentary of course. I want to clean up the model from unnecessary (irrelevant) regressors so to have better estimations of the relevant coefficients. thatßs the idea